# Not able to get Iv parameterspec from a String

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the message from FE (React Native) and send to BE to decrypt(Java Spring).
I use this [Hybrid Crypto](https://github.com/juhoen/hybrid-crypto-js) library to generate cipher text. My logic in FE is using RSA public key to create AES key, and then use this AES key to encrypt my message. I send to my BE encrypted AES key + iv + cipher text
But in Java I cannot read Iv parameterspec, it's always show this message

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long

This is my Iv, it always returns the same length with different AES standards (AES-ECB, AES-CBC, AES-CFB, AES-OFB, AES-CTR)

> merltoPCJMCEu0/yEaMpriIG9Xl4hP3W+h1iNJUndu0=

I did my own research, and I found that the Iv length in Java must always be 16 bytes

But when I decode my String, it always returns 32

```
System.out.println(Base64.getDecoder().decode("merltoPCJMCEu0/yEaMpriIG9Xl4hP3W+h1iNJUndu0=").length);
```

This is all of my decrypt code

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = generatePrivateKey(factory, RESOURCES_DIR + "private-key.pem");

Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] keyb = decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode("My AES key"));

SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(keyb, "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode("My IV string"));
Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
ci.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);

byte[] decryptOut = ci.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode("My cipher text"));
System.out.println(new String(decryptOut, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I really don't know where am I missing...

Comment: Does your FE by any chance try to use 256-bit encryption? And what Java version is your BE using?

Comment: @Thomas https://github.com/juhoen/hybrid-crypto-js/blob/master/web/hybrid-crypto.js According to FE Crypto source, I think IV size is 32 by default... I am using Java 11

Comment: Hmm, it seems Java doesn't support 256-bit blocks (i.e. 32 byte IV) by default. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html states: "AES is a _128-bit block_ cipher supporting keys of 128, 192, and 256 bits." Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132162/what-size-of-initialization-vector-needed-for-aes-256-encryption-in-java. Finally https://tools.ietf.org/doc/tcllib/html/aes.html states: "AES is a 128-bit block cipher" and "The initialization vector -iv takes a 16 byte binary argument". - So it seems your FE library is using the wrong IV.

Comment: Thank you anyway, so there is no way to continue with this FE library... took me 2 days for nothing...

Comment: Well, it seems you can pass the iv size as `options.aesIvSize` so try to pass 16 here.

Comment: @Thomas jeez, they don't include it in readme, it's now 16. Thank you so much, I wish I could buy you a coffee or something :D

Comment: You're welcome. I'll get my coffee, don't worry :)